# jQuery function bloated and uneccessary?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function that when a user clicks a button on my page, X related div has its class removed, and the class is then applied to the new corresponding div.

Ive written the following that works as I need, My only concern is it seems bloated, and if I keep adding divs, ill then have to add more buttons, and more click functions. Is their a better way to do this?

```
$('a.one').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($('.active').parent().is(':last-child')) return;
        $('.active').removeClass('active').parent().find('div.one').addClass('active');
    });
    $('a.two').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($('.active').parent().is(':last-child')) return;
        $('.active').removeClass('active').parent().find('div.two').addClass('active');
    });
    $('a.three').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($('.active').parent().is(':last-child')) return;
        $('.active').removeClass('active').parent().find('div.three').addClass('active');
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R4Cz2/

Comment: This looks like it could be DRYed up quite easily. Could you post your HTML structure too.

Comment: I've added an answer with one way you could simplify it. However, if you post the relevant HTML structure there might be a better way to do the DOM traversal.

Comment: Ive added a jsfiddle for my page @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: @Liam where? I can't see a link in your OP

Comment: Duhhh! sorry http://jsfiddle.net/R4Cz2/

Answer (score 4):

Add an additional class that is on **all** of those elements, and then use a `data-*` attribute to store the selector of the next element. So:

```
<a href="www.test.com" class="yourclass one" data-next="div.two">Test</a>
<a href="www.test.com" class="yourclass two" data-next="div.three">Test</a>
...
```

Then:

```
$('a.yourclass').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('.active').parent().is(':last-child')) return;
    $('.active').removeClass('active').parent().find($(this).data('next')).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't improve the code much as I don't know the actual HTML structure, below is the best I can do with the provided snippet:

```
// you can give all these elements a common class name to avoid listing all of them
$('a.one, a.two, a.three').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('.active').parent().is(':last-child')) return;

    var $this = $(this);
    var divClassName = 'div';

    if($this.is('.one'))
        divClassName += '.one';
    else if($this.is('.two'))
        divClassName += '.two';
    else if($this.is('.three'))
        divClassName += '.three';

    $('.active').removeClass('active').parent().find(divClassName).addClass('active');
});
```